# Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int'

Tags: python, pandas

When running the following code:

```
for row,hit in hits.iterrows():
    forwardRows = data[data.index.values > row];
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int'
```

If I look into what is being compared here I have these variables:

```
type(row)
pandas.tslib.Timestamp

row
Timestamp('2015-09-01 09:30:00')
```

is being compared with:

```
type(data.index.values[0])
numpy.datetime64

data.index.values[0]
numpy.datetime64('2015-09-01T10:30:00.000000000+0100')
```

I would like to understand whether this is something that can be easily fixed or should I upload a subset of my data?  thanks

Comment: `data[data.index.values > row]` seems like you're searching for a value of `data[True]` or `data[False]` inside your `data` dictionary. You'll need to upload a subset of your data, or give possible outputs/inputs that will allow people to see what kind of data is returned by the `iterrows()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `values` you put it into `numpy` world.  Instead, try

```
for row,hit in hits.iterrows():
    forwardRows = data[data.index > row];
```

Comment: This fixed it.  Thanks @piRSquared.

Answer (score 4):

Although this isn't a direct answer to your question, I have a feeling that this is what you're looking for: [pandas.DataFrame.truncate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.truncate.html)

You could use it as follows:

```
for row, hit in hits.iterrows():
    forwardRows = data.truncate(before=row)
```

---

Here's a little toy example of how you might use it in general:

```
import pandas as pd

# let's create some data to play with
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01', end='2016-06-01', freq='M'),
    columns=['x'],
    data=np.random.random(5)
)

# example: truncate rows before Mar 1
df.truncate(before='2016-03-01')

# example: truncate rows after Mar 1
df.truncate(after='2016-03-01')
```

Comment: Thanks Kris.  Appreciate you highlighting `DataFrame.truncate` as an option and providing an example.  I will mark up your answer.